# External and internal interfaces & information hiding in OCaml

Tags: module, ocaml

When creating a library from multiple modules, I cannot find a nice way to do proper information hiding to the user of the library (external interface) while being able to access everything I need on the internal interface.

To be more specific, I have two modules (Files a.ml[i] and b.ml[i]). In A, I define some type t, thats internals I don't want to hide from the user (external interface).

```
module A : sig
  type t
end
module A = struct
  type t = float
end
```

In module B, I then want to use the *secret* type of `A.t`.

```
module B : sig
  create_a : float -> A.t
end
module B = struct
  create_a x = x
end
```

This of course does not compile, because the compilation unit of B does not know the type of `A.t`.

Solutions I know, but don't like:

1. Move the function `create_a` to module `A`
2. Copy the definition of `A.t` to `B` and cheat the type checker with some `` external cheat : `a -> `b = "%identity" ``

Is there some other way to know the type of `A.t` in `B` without leaking this information to the library's interface?

Comment: This wording is difficult to understand, seems contradictory: "In A, I define some type t, thats internals I don't want to hide from the user (external interface)." "Internal" vs "dont wanto to hide"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As always an extra layer of indirection can solve this problem. Define a module `Lib` that will specify an external interface, e.g.,

```
module Lib : sig 
 module A : sig
   type t
   (* public interface *)
 end
 module B : sig 
    type t 
    (* public interface *)
 end = struct 
   module A = A
   module B = B
 end
```

If you don't want to repeat yourself and write module signatures twice, then you can define them once in a module `sigs.ml`:

```
 module Sigs = struct
   module type A = sig 
     type t
     (* public interface *)
   end

   (* alternatively, you can move it into sigs_priv.ml *)
   module type A_private = sig 
     include A
     val create_a : float -> t
   end

   ...
 end
```

Finally, make sure that you're not installing interfaces (the `.cmi` files),
during your installation step, so that users can't bypass your abstraction. If your're using oasis, then it is simple: just make all your modules internal, except the module `Lib`, i.e., specify them with `InternalModules` field.